# Remove blank lines at the end of MS EXCEL CSV files

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have around 300 CSV files places at a path.
These files names have 3 different categories i.e. `*_PROD.csv`, `*_DEV.csv` and `*_UAT.csv`.

These files have many blank lines (around 1000) which got inserted at the end of the records when they were copied to the path by a process.

I want to remove the blank lines from all theses files. I have to perform a merge on these files after the blank spaces are removed.

I have tried this:

```
sed -i '/^$/d' ${File_Path}*_PROD.csv
sed -i '/^$/d' ${File_Path}*_DEV.csv
sed -i '/^$/d' ${File_Path}*_UAT.csv
```

But this is not working as expected.

I want the files to remain the same because I have to perform other operations once the blank lines are removed from the end.

Please suggest.

My Script for reference:

```
File_Path=/File_Path

dos2unix ${File_Path}*_PROD.csv
dos2unix ${File_Path}*_DEV.csv
dos2unix ${File_Path}*_UAT.csv



sed -i '/^\s*$/d' ${File_Path}*_PROD.csv
sed -i '/^\s*$/d' ${File_Path}*_DEV.csv
sed -i '/^\s*$/d' ${File_Path}*_UAT.csv

awk '(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)' ${File_Path}*PROD.csv > Merged_PROD.csv
awk '(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)' ${File_Path}*_DEV.csv > Merged_DEV.csv
awk '(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)'  ${File_Path}*_UAT.csv > Merged_UAT.csv
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: The `awk`-command is supposed to drop empty input-files?

Comment: No the awk is used here to merge. I was trying to remove the empty lines and then do a merge.

Comment: You can either drop the `awk`-command then --you're already removing blank lines with sed-- or do it altogether in an `awk`-script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your csv-files will have windows-line-ends.  So you need to convert them to linux-format first.

`dos2unix yourfile` will do that for you.

If you do not have `dos2unix` on your box, the same can be achieved with...

```
sed "s/\r//" infile >outfile         # UnxUtils sed v4.0.7 or higher
tr -d \r <infile >outfile            # GNU tr version 1.22 or higher
```

according to [sed1line.txt](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt).

Once the file is converted to Unix-Format, the usual `sed`-commands should work as expected.

Watch out for spaces in otherwise blank lines: `sed '/^\s*$/d' yourfile`

All in one sed-command:

```bash
sed -e 's/\r// -e /^\s*$/d' yourfile > outputfile
```

Comment: You mean dos2unix ${File_Path}*_PROD.csv and then the sed in my script?

Comment: or do i only need to add dos2unix command before the sed?

Comment: First `dos2unix`and `sed` after that.

Comment: I have added the script for your reference. I am able to run the script fine. But now the merge is not combining the files. In the merge file i am able to get the file from first file only

Comment: For future reference: `\r` and `\s` are GNU `sed` only. Use a literal carriage return or `[[:cntrl:]]` instead of `\r` and `[[:space:]]` instead of `\s` for a portable script.

Comment: @Philippos I see the use of `[[:space:]]`. But `[[:cntrl:]]` looks like the CTRL-Key to me, not a Carriage Return?

Comment: `[:cntrl:]` is the character class for control characters, including CR

Comment: Watch out for spaces in otherwise blank lines?? Is this causing the issue?

Comment: Possibly, but maybe there are other non-printable characters involve.  `less --raw-control-chars` is helpful to examine the blank lines.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that the "blank" lines contain whitespace characters (carriage return is a notable suspect in files written by DOS or Windows programs).  We can change the pattern to take account of those:

```
sed -i -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' \
    "${File_Path}"*_{PROD,DEV,UAT}.csv
```

(N.B. also quote the variable expansion!)

Comment: I am getting error like: sed: can't read  File_Path/*_PROD.csv: No such file or directory. The file is present and has all the permissions

Comment: You didn't get this error with your own command? I can't think of any reason, but if you simply replace the `\s` of your commands with `[[:space:]]`, you should be done.

Comment: @user3901666, did you accidentally quote the `*` as well?  You could preview the filename expansions using `echo` to get the match you want.

Comment: I couldn't actually test it because i am trying to save the excel files which has empty lines to csv. But, while saving it to csv the empty lines are getting removed. Is it a known thing with csv? How can i add a blank line to csv at the end?

Comment: @TobySpeight-- I used the sed command and i happen to find one sample today. The sample file has 250 actual records and then blanks till 3K records.
The provided command is not removing the blank lines and while merging it is including those blank line as well. :(

Comment: I have the sample files but not sure how to attach it here.

Answer (score 2):

If you merged first and then deleted the empty lines, it's slightly more efficient. You can do something like this:

```
cat *_PROD.csv > MERGED_PROD.csv
dos2unix MERGED_PROD.csv
perl -i.bak -ne 'print if /\S/' MERGED_PROD.csv
```

The last perl one-liner keeps a copy of original `MERGED_PROD.csv` in `MERGED_PROD.csv.bak`. You can replace `-i.bak` with just `-i` in the above command to skip backup.

Comment: Good catch.  Sometimes it helps to take a step back and look at the problem from a different perspective :-)

Comment: I thought the merge operation will take time with blank lines.
Anyways, will it be costlier if i do sed to remove blank lines on close to 300 files?

Comment: On a typical use case, the blank lines <<< actual lines. Plus you get rid of creating multiple temporary files. and running sed on each of them.

Comment: perl -i.bak -n -e 'print if /\S/' MERGED_PROD.csv -- this is not allowing me to rename the file as i dont have permission to do that. I tried to remove -i.bak but still i can see the blank lines getting merged

Comment: This looks like some file permission issue. If you wish to skip the backing up the file, use `perl -i -ne 'print if /\S/' MERGED_PROD.csv`